# How i can pass a list of values in python sql?

Tags: python, sql

I am passing the list of values in *IN* query. When I run this query in workbench and other places it is working but not working inside the python code.

In python, it is taking values as a list so it is giving an error.

I want to pass a list of values in a Python SQL query. But it gives me an error:

> can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

I also try with the list but then it gives an error:

> can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

```
emp_id = ['470224', '471822', '470551', '471854', '471603', '468121', '458435', '466700', '471605', '471609', '471604', '458535', '454387', '469881']

mycursor.execute("select * from table_name where id in "+"'"+emp_id+"'")
```

The query must work as follows:

```
select * from table_name where id in ('470224', '471822', '470551', '471854', '471603', '468121', '458435', '466700', '471605', '471609', '471604', '458535', '454387', '469881') ;
```

It must fetch all the record which is in the IN query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emp_id = ['470224', '471822', '470551', '471854', '471603', '468121', '458435', '466700', '471605', '471609', '471604', '458535', '454387', '469881']
mycursor.execute("select * from table_name where id in " + str(tuple(emp_id)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind explaining how it works?